# Can i use MVC in my app?

Tags: ios, oop, model-view-controller

I made an app but I want to refactor it to follow a known design pattern (MVC). Can someone explain what code should be in what class

So now I have these classes:

```
ViewController
-- properties
name
age
-- methods

DetailViewController
-- properties
detail array
-- methods

FavoritesViewController (tableview)
-- properties
favorites array
-- methods

AllNamesViewController (tableview)
-- properties
name
age
-- methods
```

The app works like this:

User opens the App
-He can click question mark and gets a name and other properties back in json format. That opens the DetailViewController  and pushes the name and age into the DetailViewController's detail array.

Favorites
-He can go back to start screen and swipe to left for  FavoritesViewController and see the names he saved...when he clicks it, it goes back to the DetailsViewController and push the favorites array into the detail array.

AllNames
-He can swipe to right for all names that has all the names in a array when he clicks one it goes to the DetailViewController and pushes the array element into the array of DetailViewController.

What kind of object should be a datamodel? and how would that data model look like?

The part of json method should that always be in the controller or in the data model?

How can i determine what should be a data model.
I read a lot of books and followed the tutorials but I can never see when something should be in a data model or not.

So can someone clarify it with the app I made so that maybe I get that "OOOHH" idea :)

Comment: michaels understood my question perfectly. I am refactoring the code. I wanted to know what should be a model and what should be in the controller. What I didn't know is that you should also make different classes for methods that handle to get the "Person" object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the MVC pattern, you have three separate components: Model, View, Controller.

In iOS, a `viewController` plays the role of the Controller in the MVC pattern - it is meant to handle the communication between your view and the data.

The viewController's `view` property plays the role of View in the MVC pattern - this is the UI to be displayed.

How you implement the Model portion is up to you, but from what I understand from your question it looks like you have two responsibilities - a data object that holds your information, and storage of that data (in JSON).

I would create two classes for this, one that is just a data object (called `Person` or something, not sure what your use case is) that has properties for whatever data you need to store, and very few (if any) actual methods. The second would be some kind of storage class where you pass in Persons to be stored, and query them back (i.e. `getAll`, `getFavorites`, etc...). This class would handle conversion to and from JSON, and its interface would deal exclusively with Person objects.

Your controllers would then query this storage class, retrieve an array of Persons, and display them somehow (in a table it looks like).

Comment: thanks for the answer. So i should make a class with all the methods that connects to the webservice and gets back information that i put in a Person. The other viewcontrollers should use those methods to get a Person back ? and use that Person object to the view ? Is that what you mean... ?

Comment: I assumed you were storing the information locally, but if it's a webservice that returns your data then the concept is the same. Yes, you would have a class that retrieves your data from a server and returns it in a strongly-typed way (i.e. an array of Persons). The controller would then use that data to update its view

Comment: the first view controller gets its Person from a webservice... but the tableview with all the persons is a plist that is downloaded onto the phone and put into an array. but they all have the same output of data. So basicly i would have 2 methods...one that loads from a webservice and one from an array... but both in the same "method" class that makes a Person object and pushes that to the viewcontrollers and those viewcontrollers "understand" the Person object and use that to output to the view... this is MVC ?

Comment: Yeah that sounds about right. The view controller just takes the model objects and hands them around (i.e. retrieves them from your server class, and passes them to the view), and then reacts to events on the view if the model needs to be updated (for example, the user changes a name of a person, the controller passes the message on to a class that can persist this change)

Comment: you made it very clear thanks! i didnt know where to put the methods. I thought it would be weird to put them into the Person (Model class) but its oke to make other method classes.. i didnt get that... so model classes dont have allot of methods themselfs. In the examples they always only had proporties.